# An iron bar 20 m long is bent to form a closed plane area. What is the largest area possible?

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

**Problem:** An iron bar 20 m long is bent to form a closed plane area. What is the largest area possible?

To answer the question, it was assumed / deduced that the figure or shape that could give the largest area for the given perimeter is the circle.

**Question:** Is there a clue on the problem that states that the largest area that can be formed is through a circle? As there are other shapes the 20 m long bar can be formed. Also, we can't really tell if it's true as I think there is not enough information to answer that.

Sorry if the question seems odd. It's just so I can improve my visualization in this type of problems.

Comment: The problem is classic and is called the [isoperimetric problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality#The_isoperimetric_problem_in_the_plane).  There are elementary approaches in the plane, but they are decently long and complicated.  Your best bet is a kind of intuitive approach of looking at polygons and reasoning that you can improve things by adding more sides and making the sides as even as possible.  While not rigorous, this will be good enough for your purposes, I would think.

Answer (score 2):

The largest area that can be formed is  a circle.

The area of a circle is $A = \pi r^2$

You can find $r$ by using the perimeter formula $P = 2\pi r  = 20 \implies r= \dfrac{10}{\pi}$

So the area if a circle is made is $A = \dfrac{100}{\pi}\approx31.83 \;m^2$

Lets take regular $n$ - gons, the [area of a regular $n-$gon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon#Area) is given by ;

$A = \dfrac14ns^2\cot\bigg(\dfrac \pi n\bigg)$

where $r$ is the distance from the center to the vertex of any regular polygon.

You can see that the perimeter $P = 20 = n\cdot s  $  $\; $ where $s$ is the length of one side of the polygon .

$\implies s= \dfrac{20}n$

$\therefore A  = \displaystyle \frac 14n\frac{400}{n^2}\cot\bigg(\frac\pi n\bigg) = \frac{100}n\cot\bigg(\frac \pi n\bigg)$

for $\begin{pmatrix}n&&&&&& A\\3&&&&&&19.24\\4&&&&&&25\\5&&&&&&27.527\\6&&&&&&28.867\\7&&&&&&29.6645\\8&&&&&&30.17767\\9&&&&&&30.5275\\\vdots\\\vdots\\99999&&&&&&31.83\end{pmatrix}$

The limiting case as $n\to \infty$ (Which is basically  a circle) gives the area $A = 31.83\; m^2$.

Thus we could conclude the largest area is the circle

EDIT:

As user Aaron mentioned , this proof is not rigorous , but merely an intuitive approach to it.